# Trouble streaming audio from amazon s3 servers

Tags: esp32, audio

I am experimenting with streaming audio from servers using an ESP32 and [this](https://github.com/schreibfaul1/ESP32-audioI2S) library. I have been able to stream audio from every http server which i have tried but have had mixed success with https servers. I had originally wanted to stream audio from an amazon S3 server but could not get this to work. I have managed to get it to work using the google cloud servers (Both of these are https servers). Any thoughts on what might be the problem would be much appreciated. thanks.
I'm not sure if this is an appropriate forum but im not qute sure where else to post my question. thanks.

Comment: SSL decryption takes a lot of CPU power, that could be the culprit. And all streaming and ESP32 application I have seen has been just HTTP.

Comment: Hmm...ive actually now managed to get it streaming from my google cloud storage which is an https address. i was originally hoping to retrieve files from amazon aws since i am already using this for various other things but i get an error when trying to retreive files form these servers. Since the google cloud service works it can't be to do with the https protocol which i had originally thought.

Comment: Please change your question with that info.

Comment: hi, have updated question.